# Modify the source file in shell

Tags: shell

During creation of shell script, I am facing a problem. Actually I have a file which contain below information.

```
<FLATFILE CODEPAGE ="UTF-8" CONSECDELIMITERSASONE ="NO" DELIMITED ="YES" DELIMITERS =";" ESCAPE_CHARACTER ="" KEEPESCAPECHAR ="NO" LINESEQUENTIAL ="NO" MULTIDELIMITERSASAND ="NO" NULLCHARTYPE ="ASCII" NULL_CHARACTER ="*" PADBYTES ="1" QUOTE_CHARACTER ="NONE" REPEATABLE ="NO" ROWDELIMITER ="10" SHIFTSENSITIVEDATA ="NO" SKIPROWS ="1" STRIPTRAILINGBLANKS ="NO"/>
```

I want to modify the above file like below.

```
FLATFILE CODEPAGE ="UTF-8" 
CONSECDELIMITERSASONE ="NO" 
DELIMITED ="YES" 
DELIMITERS =";" 
ESCAPE_CHARACTER ="" 
KEEPESCAPECHAR ="NO" 
LINESEQUENTIAL ="NO" 
MULTIDELIMITERSASAND ="NO" 
NULLCHARTYPE ="ASCII" 
NULL_CHARACTER ="*" 
PADBYTES ="1" 
QUOTE_CHARACTER ="NONE" 
REPEATABLE ="NO" 
ROWDELIMITER ="10" 
SHIFTSENSITIVEDATA ="NO" 
SKIPROWS ="1" 
STRIPTRAILINGBLANKS ="NO"
```

Can anyone please help me on this.

Comment: What programming language are you using?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
sed 's:<\|\(/>\)::g;s:\(=[^ ]\+\) :\1\n:g' INPUTFILE
```

Might work for you. First it replaces the tag closing brackets. Then replaces every occurrences of the value (`="WHATEVER"`) with the value and a newline. It will work until you have a space in between those `"`s.

Comment: Thanks Zsolt..It is working. Can you please explain the above command. Why we use ":" in sed...Appreciate your support.

Comment: Since one of the search patterns contains the usual `/` delimiter, it is convenient to use a different delimiter, e. g. `:`.

Comment: @Armali is correct. You might need to read the FAQ, ( http://stackoverflow.com/helpcenter/whats-reputation ) if it works for you, you might upvote and/or accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
sed 's/^<//;s/" /"\n/g;s/\/>//' _file_
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
sed 's/ =/=/g' | tr " " "\n" | sed -e 's/<//' -e 's/>//' -e 's/\///'
```

Comment: That's way too much (just kidding) process for this simple task :-)